# Merging two json objects in Java script?

Tags: javascript, json

Have u merged two jsons in javascript ??

Problem:

```
a={id:123,name:john,status:success};
b={id:123,status:inprocess,transId:245};
```

Output json should be like

```
{id:123,name:john,status:success,transId:245};
```

All the values from a should override the ones in b and also the uncommon key/values should appear in output json.

I tried out some recursive options but cudnt acheive the output.

Comment: That's not JSON, that is Javascript objects. JSON is a test format for representing objects.

Comment: It's been asked so many times:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154712/javascript-extending-an-object-question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430279/javascript-object-extending
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585168/javascript-extending-object-with-multiple-properties

Comment: Hi oleq, i tried those links but cudnt achieve the needed result.I was careful to already search the stack before asking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your `a` and `b` variable are not valid json.

```
<script>
//change your a and b variable to this.
 a={id:123,name:'john',status:'success'}; 
 b={id:123,status:'inprocess',transId:245};
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.extend(a,b);

});
</script>
```

and `a` will have structure like

```
{
    id: 123
    name: "john"
    status: "inprocess"
    transId: 245
 
}
```

I've used jquery api

## update.

without jquery

```
   a={id:123,name:'john',status:'success'}; 
   b={id:123,status:'inprocess',transId:245};

  extend(a,b);
```

where extend function is:

```
 function extend(a, b){
    for(var key in b)
        if(b.hasOwnProperty(key))
            a[key] = b[key];
    return a;
 }
```

[ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154712/javascript-extending-an-object-question) ,[ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10430279/javascript-object-extending) , [ref3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197247/javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-extend-method)

Comment: Are you using a library there?

Comment: Hi Manish, now it leaves out the properties in b and updates only the ones in a.

Comment: wow, if you want b also to be updated according to a, call extend(b,a); what's the point of overwriting one of the objects then?? anyways

Answer (score 0):

It's simple

```
for (var p in a)
   b[p] = a[p];
```

Comment: but what about nested jsons , how do i acheive the result ?

Comment: this case you'll need to use a recursion for nested objects. Use instanceof to detect it.

Answer (score -1):

```
let x = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3  
}

let y = {
  c: 4, 
  d: 5,
  e: 6
}

let z = Object.assign(x, y)

console.log(z)

z:
{
  a:1,
  b:2,
  c:4, 
  d:5,
  e:6,
}
```

---> NOTICE : the object z take the y's c attribute